# Can $(g(x)*h(x))'$ be non-monotonic when $g'(x)$ and $h'(x)$ are monotonic?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, functions, derivatives, products

Basically, I am wondering when the derivative of a product will be "nice" in the sense that if each term has derivatives that are monotonic than the product will have a derivative that is monotonic.

---

Using the product rule,
$$
(g(x)*h(x))' = g(x)h'(x) + g'(x)h(x)
$$

If $g,h$ are both positive and non-increasing (non-decreasing) then it is clear that $(g(x)*h(x))'$ will be non-increasing (becuase each term will be negative).

I'm sure a similar logic will hold if both $g,h$ are negative.

> if $g,h$ are og opposite signs, though, or if their derivatives are of opposite signs, then we cannot sign the terms, and so I think the product can be non-monotonic?
>
> - If possible, can someone provide an example where $g'(x)$ and $h'(x)$ are monotonic, but $(g(x)*h(x))'$ is **really** non-monotonic (by really, I mean it switch from increasing to decreasing and back more than once)

Comment: You should use \cdot (looks like this: $\cdot$) to avoid a confusion with convolution

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x)= x\,\forall \,x\in R$ and  $ g(x)=(x-2)\,\forall\,x\in R$
$$ $$
$f(x)$ and $g(x)$ both are monotonic $\forall\,x\in R$
$$. $$
But $h(x)=f(x)g(x)=x(x-2)=(x-1)^2-1$. Is decreasing for $x\lt 1$. And increasing for $x\gt1$.